# Datepicker enable all date

Tags: jquery, date

I have an datepicker that work as start date and end date for my project. But I've noticed that the future date are disabled, How can I enable all dates?

```
 $("#CmpnyLastTxn,#CmpnyLastVst,#CPinvite,#CPTxn").datepicker({
            maxDate: new Date(),
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
                if (!$(this).data().datepicker.first) {
                    $(this).data().datepicker.inline = true
                    $(this).data().datepicker.first = selectedDate;
                } else {
                    $(this).val($(this).data().datepicker.first + " - " + selectedDate);
                    $(this).data().datepicker.inline = false;
                }
            },
            onClose: function () {
                delete $(this).data().datepicker.first;
                $(this).data().datepicker.inline = false;
            }
        })
```

Comment: You actualy set `maxDate` to current date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set Your maxDate param, or set it to null.

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate